# I used Bootstrap 4 for a navbar. I can't change the background-color of the wrapping div element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

A few things that I've tried: 
background-color: transparent; ,
rgba(0,0,0,0); , 
background: none;

However, when i try `background-color: red` or any other color, it changes color accordingly.

Here is my HTML code:

```
`<div class="navbar  navbar-expand-md">
  <h1 class="navbar-brand">sivarajbiz</h1>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">What you want</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">What I know</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Let's chat</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
:root{
  --primary-theme-color: #0077B5 /*LinkedInBlue*/;
  --buttons-color: #0077B5 /*LinkedInBlue*/;
  --primary-bg-color: black;
  --primary-font-color: white;
  --img-text-bg-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.2);
  --img-text-font-size-mobile: 0.8em;
  --img-text-box-width: 20em;
  --img-text-box-width-mobile: 15em;
}

body{
  font-family: "times new roman",serif;
  color: var(--primary-font-color);
  background-color: var(--primary-bg-color);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-caption{
  transform: translate(-5vw,-30vh);
  background-color: var(--img-text-bg-color);
  width: var(--img-text-box-width);
  height: var(--img-text-box-width);
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
```

As shown in the image, the navbar is black in colour, by default. I would like to change it to be transparent.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate as to which element background color you want to change?

Comment: the wrapper div element's bg  `<div class="navbar  navbar-expand-md">`

Comment: All the colors you have applied is transparent. It won't change any background color. What else do you expect? As soon as you add any solid color it changes. It is expected behavior.

Comment: Show us your css. What you are getting and what exactly you are aiming for.
Please improve your question.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas it has a black background right now, without me adding any styles of my own.

Comment: you already put background to your body. how could you expect transparent black show to you.

Comment: i've tried changing the bg color of the body to transparent and for some reason, it still doesn't seem to work. I've also tried removing the `background-color` of the body altogether but the navbar 's background is still black

Comment: @SIVARAJGHANESHALTHANASAGAR Where is your CSS targeting the navbar?

Comment: check my solution an let me know please is that you wanted :) @SIVARAJGHANESHALTHANASAGAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving the background image to the `top: 0;` and adding a z-index `z-index:10;` to the navbar element did the trick. Finally, the navbar is showing the part of the image behind it as the background.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly...

If you pay attention to your css you are going to see that the body color is being set to black. Thus, if you leave transparent the body .css will apply and the colour will be black.

If you need to set to background transparent (so the image is displayed as background instead) you need to set the body as transparent:

`body{
 background-color: transparent;
}`

Answer (score 1):

To remove background color you need to remove `background-color: var(--primary-bg-color);` this css from your body style. checkout this codepen https://codepen.io/irinnahar/pen/NZOqjO

Comment: the solution that worked for me has just a couple of extra lines of codes( stated in my answer to this question) from your codepen example. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: my pleasure i could help you. :D tnx for accepting my answer as well

Comment: @iwaduarte it isn't actually. Just that the light bulb lighted up when i saw the codepen example. Thank You as well for helping out. My apologies for not giving credit to you sooner.

Comment: It is okay. I think you question was not what you have been looking for after all. But glad you work it out. :)

Answer (score -1):

What about using the css`!important` word?

Like this: `background-color:rgba(255,0,0,1) !important;`